# Can any value of SharedPreferences be retrieved as String?

Tags: java, android

`SharedPreferences` provides `put` and `get` access for storing `Boolean`, `Float`, `Integer`, `Long`, and `String`. Since they are all saved in an xml file, is it safe to assume that `sharedPreferences.getString(...)` will return the non-String value as a String and not throw any exception?

Comment: getstring will always return a string value

Comment: @KhizarHayat yes, but if I store an Integer value of 111, will it return a String value of "111"?

Comment: at time of put what was your code ?

Comment: if you use sharedPreferences.putString("tag","1111");
then yes you can get it as string because you have stroed string not int

Comment: @KhizarHayat I just need to know it I do `putInt("key", "111")`, I could do `getString("key", "")`

Comment: putInt("key","111") gives you an error. you cant do this

Comment: @KhizarHayat I think I meant `putInt("key", 111)`, but I think a valid answer has been provided. I thank you for your support.

Comment: Why on Earth do you want to use `getString()` instead og the proper `getXYZ()` methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just try it out, but according to the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getString%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

> `String getString(String key, String defValue)`
>
> Returns the preference value if it exists, or defValue. **Throws ClassCastException if** there is a preference with this name that is **not a String**.

So: No.

Answer (score 0):

Store the value as string and get it in string from the SharedPreference. you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sharedPreferences would return the value in same data type with which it is stored. If we use: sharedPreferences.putString("tag","1111"), .getString() will return 1111 as string.
And, if we use sharedPreference.putInt("tag",1111), .getInt() will return 1111 as int.